# How to create IBPlugins for Xcode 4

Tags: xcode4

I was wondering if anyone has any information on how to create an IBPlugin using Xcode 4 for use in Xcode 4.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like a big no go for IBPlugin Creation in Xcode 4
http://www.osomac.com/2011/03/18/remove-ib-plugins-from-xcode/